# Problem installing Apache web server in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I see this code in red after trying to install `apache`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
...
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-09-27 15:18:07 +0330; 8ms ago
  Process: 8805 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
and 
End of code:Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot comment yet so i have to put this as an answer. 
did you adjust your firewall?
what is the output of sudo ufw app list
If Apache in the list of Output than run sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
than restart the service sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: digital ocean has a great step by step instruction on how to install Apache https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04